# create .exe from .py tensorflow import dll error

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a .exe from my python script with `pyinstaller`.
The .exe starts fine on this system.
But when i move the file to another system without python installed and try to start i got the error on cmd.

```
C:\output\predict>predict.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\charly\anaconda3\envs\audio\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "c:\users\charly\anaconda3\envs\audio\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "c:\users\charly\anaconda3\envs\audio\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "c:\users\charly\anaconda3\envs\audio\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
[10436] Failed to execute script predict
```

what i'm missing there ?
do i have to add the tensorflow path manually?
hope you guys can help me with this